# reading text file and capturing content in an array using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file having content in it as below. i want to get data within "HEALTH_AT_A_GLANCE" in one array and data within "FIRMWARE_INFORMATION" in another array excluding INDEX*
My question is how to achieve it. I tried a lot but not working for me, please suggest

```
HEALTH_AT_A_GLANCE
BIOS_HARDWARE STATUS= OK
FANS STATUS= OK
FANS REDUNDANCY= Redundant
TEMPERATURE STATUS= OK
POWER_SUPPLIES STATUS= OK
POWER_SUPPLIES REDUNDANCY= Redundant
BATTERY STATUS= OK
PROCESSOR STATUS= OK
MEMORY STATUS= OK
NETWORK STATUS= OK
STORAGE STATUS= OK
HEALTH_AT_A_GLANCE
FIRMWARE_INFORMATION
INDEX_1
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = ILO
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 2.44 Apr 30 2021
INDEX_1
INDEX_2
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = System ROM
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = U30 v2.50 (05242021)
INDEX_2
INDEX_3
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Redundant System ROM
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = U30 v2.50 (05242021)
INDEX_3
INDEX_4
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Intelligent Platform Abstraction Data
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 15.2.0 Build 51
INDEX_4
INDEX_5
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Power Management Controller Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 1.0.7
FIRMWARE_FAMILY VALUE = 19h
INDEX_5
INDEX_6
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Power Management Controller FW Bootloader
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 1.1
INDEX_6
INDEX_7
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = System Programmable Logic Device
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 0x31
INDEX_7
INDEX_8
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 4.1.4.505
INDEX_8
INDEX_9
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HPE Smart Storage Energy Pack 1 Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 0.70
INDEX_9
INDEX_10
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Intelligent Provisioning
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 3.64.2
INDEX_10
INDEX_11
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Innovation Engine (IE) Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 0.2.2.2
INDEX_11
INDEX_12
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Embedded Video Controller
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 2.5
INDEX_12
INDEX_13
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 3.53
INDEX_13
INDEX_14
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HP Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 366FLR Adapter
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 1.2836.0
INDEX_14
INDEX_15
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 
INDEX_15
FIRMWARE_INFORMATION
```

Required as below:
array1 will hold below data

```
ILO ->2.44 Apr 30 2021    
System ROM -> U30 v2.50 (05242021)
Redundant System ROM ->U30 v2.50 (05242021)
Intelligent Platform Abstraction Data ->15.2.0 Build 51
Power Management Controller Firmware ->1.0.7
Power Management Controller FW Bootloader -> 1.1
System Programmable Logic Device -> 0x31       
Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware -> 4.1.4.505
HPE Smart Storage Energy Pack 1 Firmware -> 0.70         
Intelligent Provisioning -> 3.64.2
Innovation Engine (IE) Firmware -> 0.2.2.2    
Embedded Video Controller -> 2.5
HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10 -> 3.53
HP Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 366FLR Adapter ->1.2836.0
```

Array2 will hold below data:

```
BIOS_HARDWARE STATUS= OK
FANS STATUS= OK
FANS REDUNDANCY= Redundant
TEMPERATURE STATUS= OK
POWER_SUPPLIES STATUS= OK
POWER_SUPPLIES REDUNDANCY= Redundant
BATTERY STATUS= OK
PROCESSOR STATUS= OK
MEMORY STATUS= OK
NETWORK STATUS= OK
STORAGE STATUS= OK
```

I wrote the below code, its picking INDEX only till 8 after that not picking. how to get all INDEX data?

````
$patternarr = @()
$array = @()
$result = ""

$string = Get-Content $importpath
foreach ($line in $string)
{
    if ($line -like "*INDEX_*")
    {
        $patternarr+= $line.Substring($line.length -1, 1)
    }
}
$patternmax = $patternarr | measure -Maximum
$patternmax
$patternnr = $patternmax.Maximum
For ($i=0; $i -lt $patternnr; $i++)
{
    $pattern ="INDEX_$i(.*?)INDEX_$i"
    $result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].value
    $array += $result.replace("                FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = ","").replace("               FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = ","-> ").replace("                FIRMWARE_FAMILY VALUE = 19h","")
}
$array```
````

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and where you think it's failing at. Also, properly format the code when you update the post with it, and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as base script.

```
$x = @"
HEALTH_AT_A_GLANCE
BIOS_HARDWARE STATUS= OK
FANS STATUS= OK
FANS REDUNDANCY= Redundant
TEMPERATURE STATUS= OK
POWER_SUPPLIES STATUS= OK
POWER_SUPPLIES REDUNDANCY= Redundant
BATTERY STATUS= OK
PROCESSOR STATUS= OK
MEMORY STATUS= OK
NETWORK STATUS= OK
STORAGE STATUS= OK
HEALTH_AT_A_GLANCE
FIRMWARE_INFORMATION
INDEX_1
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = ILO
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 2.44 Apr 30 2021
INDEX_1
INDEX_2
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = System ROM
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = U30 v2.50 (05242021)
INDEX_2
INDEX_3
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Redundant System ROM
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = U30 v2.50 (05242021)
INDEX_3
INDEX_4
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Intelligent Platform Abstraction Data
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 15.2.0 Build 51
INDEX_4
INDEX_5
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Power Management Controller Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 1.0.7
FIRMWARE_FAMILY VALUE = 19h
INDEX_5
INDEX_6
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Power Management Controller FW Bootloader
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 1.1
INDEX_6
INDEX_7
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = System Programmable Logic Device
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 0x31
INDEX_7
INDEX_8
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 4.1.4.505
INDEX_8
INDEX_9
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HPE Smart Storage Energy Pack 1 Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 0.70
INDEX_9
INDEX_10
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Intelligent Provisioning
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 3.64.2
INDEX_10
INDEX_11
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Innovation Engine (IE) Firmware
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 0.2.2.2
INDEX_11
INDEX_12
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = Embedded Video Controller
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 2.5
INDEX_12
INDEX_13
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 3.53
INDEX_13
INDEX_14
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HP Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 366FLR Adapter
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 1.2836.0
INDEX_14
INDEX_15
FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = HPE Smart Array P816i-a SR Gen10
FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = 
INDEX_15
FIRMWARE_INFORMATION
"@

$l = $x.Split("`n")

$l1 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
$l2 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()

$startH = $false
$startF = $false
$nextasvalue = $false
$header = ""

foreach($line in $l) {
    if ($line -match "HEALTH_AT_A_GLANCE") {
        if ($startH) {
            $startH = $false
        } else {
            $startH = $true
        }
        continue
    }

    if ($line -match "FIRMWARE_INFORMATION") {
        if ($startF) {
            $startF = $false
        } else {
            $startF = $true
        }
        continue
    }

    if ($line -match "^INDEX") {
        continue
    }

    if ($startH) {
        $l1.Add($line)
    }

    if ($startF) {
        if ($nextasvalue) {
            $value = $line.Split("=")[1].Trim()
            $l2.Add("$header ->$value")
            $nextasvalue = $false
        }
        else {
            $header = $line.Split("=")[1].Trim()
            $nextasvalue = $true
        }
    }
}

$l1
$l2
```

Comment: I wrote a code which i added in question area, its picking up INDEX as expected but only till Index_8 not after that. please suggest.

Comment: I've provided a complete answer and working solution, if you want to use regular expressions, up to you, but I'm not there to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by using code line `$pattern ="INDEX_$i(.*?)INDEX_$i"`